# Polling for transactions -- possible scalability issues?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, scalability

We are generating a few thousand addresses by an offline wallet, and plan to run a bitcoind node to check for incoming transfers. The idea is to check an address e.g. every second and get the list of corresponding transactions. So, we're going to have a few thousand RPC calls to our node per second (we cannot check all account-related transactions with one request since the account only exists on our wallet which stays offline for security reasons).

Questions: will it scale well? Has anybody tried sending 1000's requests/second to a bitcoind daemon? Can we send them in parallel?

If anybody can suggest a better way of doing this, please share.